# How to solve java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: android, mysql, json

i making an android application where the user can access data from database mysql (i'm using localhost phpmyadmin) and display the data with listview and i found this code on a tutorial. but show up error java.lang.NullPointerException. i don't know how to fix the error cause actually i'm still a newbie. here the view_sektor.java:

```
package com.project;


 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import java.util.HashMap;


 import org.json.JSONArray;

 import org.json.JSONException;

 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.ListActivity;

 import android.content.Intent;

 import android.os.Bundle; 
 import android.view.View;

 import android.widget.AdapterView;

 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

 import android.widget.ListAdapter;

 import android.widget.ListView;

 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class view_sektor extends ListActivity {


 private static String link_url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/check-sektor.php";


private static final String AR_ID = "id_sektor";

private static final String AR_NS = "nama_sektor";


JSONArray sektor = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> daftar_sektor = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,   String>>();


@Override

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.view_sektor);



    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


    JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);


    try {

        sektor = json.getJSONArray("sektor");


        for(int i = 0; i < sektor.length(); i++){

            JSONObject ar = sektor.getJSONObject(i);


            String id_sektor = ar.getString(AR_ID);

            String nama_sektor = ar.getString(AR_NS).substring(0,100)+"...(baca selengkapnya)";


            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


            map.put(AR_ID, id_sektor);

            map.put(AR_NS, nama_sektor);

            daftar_sektor.add(map);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    this.adapter_listview();

}

public void adapter_listview() {


    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, daftar_sektor,

            R.layout.list_sektor,

            new String[] { AR_ID, AR_NS}, new int[] {

                    R.id.id_sektor, R.id.nama_sektor});


    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();


}
 }
```

and here the whole logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project/com.project.komoditas}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project/com.project.view_sektor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project/com.project.view_sektor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
at com.project.komoditas.onCreate(komoditas.java:26)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.project.view_sektor.onCreate(view_sektor.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: Stack Trace mate, the log cat?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project/com.project.komoditas}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project/com.project.view_sektor}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @kimyr post your entire stack trace.

Comment: @Tamilan Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project/com.project.komoditas}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project/com.project.view_sektor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project/com.project.view_sektor}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @kimyr we need to know which line in `view_sektor.class` getting `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Tamilan i already add the whole logcat. check it

Comment: @kimyr what is the line number 70 in `view_sektor.class` **(view_sektor.java:70)**

Comment: line 70 is between for(int i = 0; i < sektor.length(); i++){ and JSONObject ar = sektor.getJSONObject(i); @Tamilan

Comment: @kimyr print your `json` response and post it. i guess `json` is empty

Comment: @Tamilan my json? i can't got what your point. where i can print the json response? sorry i dunno

Comment: @kimyr print like this.. `Log.v("json",""+json.toString());` you can see that response in `logcat`

Comment: @Tamilan i already print that and still error

Comment: @kimyr can you show us the response.

Comment: here: pic.twitter.com/kvmo6bD9Um & pic.twitter.com/AWLqFyF3DP

Comment: @kimyr what is the line number 67 in `view_sektor.class` and after `JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);` this line add this line `Log.v("json",""+json.toString());` and post the `logcat`

Comment: here the respon: pic.twitter.com/5k2Cbh7g0w & pic.twitter.com/qnH6RaGo3m

Comment: @kimyr check out my ans and change it and try.

Answer (score 0):

check your data is json array or not and sektor = json.getJSONArray("sektor"); sektor ia available or not

Comment: yes my sektor = json.getJSONArray("sektor");
what u mean by data and where i can see the sektor is avaiable or not? @karthik

Comment: run u r url in browser check sektor available or not.if sektor available check is it json array or json object.

Comment: when i use the url for activity it works but when i use the url for ListActivity its not work. so i run the url in browser as you said and it's not avaiable. i got confused. so how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..  you have to **initilize** that `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();  

json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();  

json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);

Log.v("json",""+json.toString());
```

Comment: still error now at line 69: Log.v("jParser",""+json.toString());

Comment: @kimyr is that first log `Log.v("jParser",""+jParser.toString());` is displayed.

Comment: yup. i also diplayed that

Comment: @kimyr what result came when you ran that URL in browser.. Could you please display that?

Comment: @kimyr then if the server could not be reached then it will throw error.. You should be able to catch those exceptions..

Comment: but when i use that url for another code (i was use that url for develop an activity and it was fine and work) but when i use that url for my listactivity it errors. so how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

try this way
Initialize the listview

call the `set Adapter` method to the `list view` and create one new class like listmaeth in the apdater method like `listmaeth`(this,values)

```
class listmaeth extends BaseAdapter{
//display what are the values you got
}
```

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. can you give me a link or a code for me to fix this?